# WLST to check the PermGen usage

Tags: weblogic, jython, permgen, wlst

I would like to get the Max Perm Gen and Usage of a server in WL Domain using WLST.
SO far I was able to see it's possible to get the information from JMX, mBean.
The mBean location is "java.lang:Location=Server1,name=PS Perm Gen,type=MemoryPool"

I tried below code but it doesn't seem working.

```
testObject=ObjectName('java.lang:Location=Server1,name=PS Perm Gen,type=MemoryPool')
```

Or Trying below code didn't work either.

```
testBean=getMBean('javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData:Location=Server1,name=Usage,type=PS Perm Gen')
for item in testBean:
    print item.getKey() + ':' + item.getValue()
```

Please help.

Update: -------------------------------------------------
Thanks for the quick reply. There's no WLST code to share in related to my topic yet because I'm trying to explore the possibility out of my search.

Basically, I'm trying to check the available Perm Gen size within WLST run before deploying an artefact to a WL managed server.

This is because WebLogic is not releasing the undeployed artefact's non-heap memory space out of WL managed server and if you keep doing deployment/undeployment without recycling, the WL managed server will eventually throw OOME of Perm Gen space.

We are trying the service outage as minimum and keeping the WL managed server up and running as long as possible.
I've searched everywhere about the WLST mBean tree location to get the non-heap memory status but failed.

But if you use JManage, you can get non-heap memory status through mBean object "java.lang:Location=Server1,name=PS Perm Gen,type=MemoryPool".

It will show like below in JManage:

```
Object Name java.lang:Location=Server1,name=PS Perm Gen,type=MemoryPool

Class Name sun.management.MemoryPoolImpl 
Description Information on the management interface of the MBean 
Configured Name       Add to Application
```

So I was wondering why is it not possible to extract the mBean info from WLST if the mBean is there? So I'm trying to get help about anyone who had similar experience/situation.

Comment: Where did you find that example? You can get generic heap usage from WLST like what is shown here: http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=1917 or http://www.yenlo.nl/nl/start-stop-and-check-status-weblogic-using-wlst/

Comment: Thanks, mkstemp, but as you know those are heap usage, and Perm Gen memory is outside of heap area.

Comment: Coud you please share your exception, error stack so that we can help

Comment: Have a look at weblogic's document on "Using the Platform MBean Server" : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24415/understandwls.htm#JMXCU239 Looks like you have to be in the custom() mbean tree

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you can connect to a managed server and then use something like this:

```
permObjectName=ObjectName('java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Perm Gen')
usoPerm=mbs.getAttribute(permObjectName,'Usage')
usoPerm.get('max') #Returns MaxPermSize in bytes
usoPerm.get('used') #Returns used Perm Space in bytes
```

However, I have tested this in several servers and it doesn't always work because the MBeanServer (mbs) is not able to 'see' the "java.lang" mbean tree.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic has different mbean hierarchies for different purposes. It considers all non-weblogic mbeans as "custom", and as such they reside in the "custom" tree.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24415/understandwls.htm#JMXCU239

To get the permgen usage of the machine you are connected to:

```
cd('custom:/java.lang/java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=PS Perm Gen')
permgen=get("Usage").get("used")
```

If you are connected to a domain admin and want to get the information for a different server:

```
cd('domainCustom:/java.lang/java.lang:Location='+servername+',name=PS Perm Gen,type=MemoryPool')
permgen=get("Usage").get("used")
```